# How to retrieve awareness timezone datetime objects with PyMongo

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, datetime, pymongo-3.x

I'm facing a problem with PyMongo 3.9 and datetime objects. In my MongoDB 4.x server I have a document like this one:

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "status" : "Running",
    "start_date" : ISODate("2020-11-19T05:03:54.576Z")
}
```

As you see, the `start_date` is in UTC zone, but the timezone is lost when I retrieve the document with PyMongo:

```
db.get_collection('my_collection').find_one({'_id': {'$eq': 2}})
```

I have read here https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/codec_options.html that Mongo returns by default a naive timezone datetime and, in order to get an awareness timezone datetime, I should add this option to the query:

```
opts=CodecOptions(tz_aware=True)
db.get_collection('my_collection', codec_options=opts).find_one({'_id': {'$eq': 99}})
```

But this means relying on the developer's memory to remember to add this option to each query. So my question is: **Is there any way to configure MongoDB, PyMongo or whatever to always return awareness timezone datetime objects?**

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it at the [MongoClient](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#module-pymongo.mongo_client) level with the `tz_aware` parameter.

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient(tz_aware=True)
```